# Focus (the TextBox of) AutoCompleteBox in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, focus, autocompletebox

I have an AutoCompleteBox in a C# WPF project. What I want is to have this box automatically focussed when the view is opened. I know there are some solutions out there in code, but I want to do this directly in the XAML (if possible).

So far I've tried the following, but it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
<controls:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="Items" ... Text="{Binding Search, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <controls:AutoCompleteBox.TextBoxStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
        </Style>
    </controls:AutoCompleteBox.TextBoxStyle>
</controls:AutoCompleteBox>
```

Comment: Anything you can code to do that can be done with a `Behavior` or `AttachedProperty`

Comment: Web search by "wpf focus xaml" produces a lot of results.

Comment: @Dennis Yes, for TextBoxes, not for AutoCompleteBox. I could only find like 4 results and all of them were in code, none in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ContainerXYZ FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=Items}">
    <controls:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="Items" ... Text="{Binding Search, Mode=TwoWay}">
</ContainerXYZ>
```

Something like this should do the trick

Comment: I've tried your code (where ContainerXYZ is my Grid), but it also doesn't work. The AutoCompleteBox isn't focused.

Comment: Did you try setting the FocusManager in different locations like the Window or the Usercontrol defintion? Maybe use a RelativeSource Binding explicitly

Comment: I am also not sure if Setting the Focus in Style works. And your Targettype in Style should be AutoCompleteBox instead of Textbox

Comment: In the Usercontrol it also doesn't work. And about your second comment, if I would change the TargetType in Style to AutoCompleteBox it gives an "unsupported for WPF" error.

Comment: TargetType="{x:Type controls:AutoCompleteBox}" ?

You should consider learning more WPF Basics